# HTML mailchimp not fully rendering iOS Outlook App

Tags: iphone, outlook, html-email, mailchimp

Has anyone run into issues for HTML email development (mailchimp) where the email won't fully render in portrait mode of iphone (10.3.2)?

https://litmus.com/community/discussions/5144-outlook-app-on-ios-not-displaying-images

It renders OK on my phone, but not our tester's or client's phone (same version).

It will briefly display and then get cut off, or if you switch to landscape mode it's viewable.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue a few months ago and the same litmus forum helped me answer my question.

A basic breakdown from the forum is:

> If you have configured email id of Outlook or Live with outlook.com or live.com domain (xyz@outlook.com or xyz@live.com), then in the Outlook App will render with the desktop in new app.
>
> And If you have configured email id of other email clients other than outlook.com or live.com domains (xyz@gmail.com or xyz@yahoo.com or @xyz.com, etc...), then it will render with responsive layout.

Source: [Litmus Forum](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/6275-how-do-you-test-responsive-emails-on-android-clients)

Now i am not sure but i would say both of you are using similar/identical version of iOS app but different email addresses for testing.

Hope this is what you were after.